# CSS Text hightlight without space

Tags: javascript, css

Hey I was wondering if it's possible in css(or maybe javascript) when highlighting the text to affect only the words? (without the in between space)

For example as seen in this website [loungelizard.com](http://www.loungelizard.com/)

```
#somediv::selection{background: #ffb7b7;}
```

thus far this only change the whole text-selected color

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe something like:

```css
p::selection {
  background-color: transparent;
  color: red;
}

div {
  color: white;
  background: blue;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <p>Some great text.</p>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you! Didn't expected to be that easy.Nevermind

Answer (score 1):

The CSS from their site:

```css
::-moz-selection {
    background-color: #fff;
    color: #111;
}
::selection {
    background-color: #fff;
    color: #ff7264;
}
::-moz-selection {
    background-color: #fff;
    color: #ff7264;
}
```

```html
<p>This is text and I love bacon</p>
```

The difference is setting the background color.

Comment: Thank you for the quick response! This answer is tottaly right but I think Marty answered first..anyway thanks again and have a nice day!

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean like this:

```html
<p>
<span style="background:blue">Bacon</span> <span style="background:blue">is</span> <span style="background:blue">Awesome</span>
</p>
```

I belive this is what you are looking for

Answer (score -1):

I dont know what exactly you are speaking of but i think it is the border.

css for a border goes like this:

```
     p{
margin-right: 20px;
border: 2px solid ##F89B29;">
}
```

or you can do this if you want the font color

```
    p{
color:red;
}
```